# Access Denied Error While Loading Images from AWS S3 Buckets

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to load my static image files using AWS S3 Buckets in my Django Project, but I am getting access denied error. I created a IAM user and granted full access to S3. I also installed django-storages and boto3. I have added 'storages' in INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py

This is the error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>41C48F59569D1B9F</RequestId>
<HostId>OBKr0zh+DmpcbvesTTFi9wLmKb4Y8GMgg7knOMKlcVBLkU47SKPEyttj4sUjY3cbu8hkfjCpos0=</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is my settings.py configuration:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '***'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '***'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket-name'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'
```

This is my CORS code:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

This is my Bucket-Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "ExamplePolicy01",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::sample"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just asking if this is the pattern you have in your policy `arn:aws:iam::sample` as you shared in the OP. Because it is not correct. It should be something like `arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/<Your username>`. Another thing why. you are adding ARN  `Principal` based auth when you want `PublicReadForGetBucketObjects`

Comment: Yes, the pattern is same as arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/<Your username>

Comment: @samtoddler Is Bucket Policy necessary to add if we want to simply load static images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to go to Permissions tab and uncheck Block all public access.
Then in the properties tab of the bucket there is an option called 'Static Website Hosting'. You need to enable it and set configurations. In my case, I used 'Redirect Request' and set the url path as 'http://bucket-name.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'

Then, I checked select all box to select all the individual static files and in Actions I selected 'Make Public'

This helped me to load my static files in Django Project.

My CORS code is:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

My Bucket Policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "ExamplePolicy01",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/bucket"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the bucket policy is in correct format:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "ExamplePolicy01",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/bucket"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How is that different from the answer of @Cute Panda?

Answer (score 0):

You can just allow public reads on the bucket via the policy
[Granting Read-Only Permission to an Anonymous User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If I implement "Principal": "*", I am getting API Response as Access Denied

Comment: @MalayParmar as per the documentation it should not return any error, and with the above policy public reads are allowed, can you check  under permisions section in aws console for `Block public access (bucket settings)` if you have blocked all the public access

Comment: I manually went to a single image and changed its permission to give Read Permission for Public access. Now the file is loading successfully. Do we manually have to configure this for all static files??

Comment: No, you don't have to do it manually for all objects, policy should be able take care of that. Check `Permissions` section under your bucket, [By default, new buckets, access points, and objects don't allow public access. However, users can modify bucket policies, access point policies, or object permissions to allow public access. S3 Block Public Access settings override these policies and permissions so that you can limit public access to these resources.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html)

Comment: Yeah, I unchecked it already, but still if I upload a new image to the bucket, I have to manually alter the Read Permission to grant public access

Comment: @MalayParmar yes when you upload the object, you have to set the ACL.

Comment: One more thing, I had to edit the Static website hosting in Properties, Enabled it and set Hosting type to 'Redirect request' and provided the request url to make it work

Comment: @MalayParmar  Glad, it worked out. Can you mark the question as solved? This helps the community and anyone who stumble upon this question

Comment: @MalayParmar always keep the documentation handy and use canned policies. They work most of the time and saves time :)